# Ошибка при попытке сборки проекта Hello World Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+

Tags: android, android-sdk, intellij-idea

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь собрать свое первое приложение для android

```
ОС Windwows 10,
Intellige IDEA 2017.2
JDK jdk1.8.0_161
Android API 27 Platform
Gradle 4.6
Android SDK 25.5.2
```

установленные пакеты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

возвращается ошибка

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+.
     Versions that do not match:
         26.0.0-alpha1
         25.3.1
         25.3.0
         25.2.0
         25.1.1
         + 31 more
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:27.+.
     Versions that do not match:
         26.0.0-alpha1
         25.3.1
         25.3.0
         25.2.0
         25.1.1
         + 21 more
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых я бы Вам посоветовал поставить все-таки Android Studio вместо Inteleji IDE. 
Если нет, то откройте файл gradle>app и измените версию поддержки `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+` на версию `v7:25.3.1` и версию дизайна соответственно `com.android.support:design:27.+` тоже на `v7:25.3.1`. Далее в правом верхнем углу нажать на Synch Now, должно заработать.